# ASP.NET Core Web API - Fluent Validation not validating user Login Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am implementing Fluent Validation. I have this code.

Model:

```
public class OAuthLoginRequest
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}

public class OAuthLoginResponse
{
    public string response_code { get; set; }
    public string response_description { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    public string expires_in { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
}
```

Validation:

```
public class OAuthLoginRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<OAuthLoginRequest>
{
    public OAuthLoginRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(user => user.username)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Username field is required.");

        RuleFor(user => user.password)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Password field is required.");
    }
}
```

AuthService:

```
   public async Task<OAuthLoginResponse> Login(OAuthLoginRequest payload)
    {
        var response = new OAuthLoginResponse();
        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            try
            {
                var authEndpoint = _config.GetSection("Endpoints").GetValue<string>("authEndpoint");
                string url = baseUrl + authEndpoint;

                var request = new OAuthLoginRequest
                {
                    username = payload.username,
                    password = payload.password
                };
                var header = new Dictionary<string, string> { };

                var httpResponse = await _httpHelper.PostOrPutRequest(uri: url, methodType: HttpMethod.Post, model: request, headers: header);
                if (httpResponse != null)
                {
                    if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuthLoginResponse>(content);
                    }
                }
                transaction.Complete();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("An Error occured " + ex.ToString());
                response = null;
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route(ApiRoutes.Login)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<OAuthLoginResponse>> Login([FromBody] OAuthLoginRequest request)
    {
        var result = await _myService.Login(request);
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Dependency Injection:

```
public static class DIServiceExtension
{
    public static void AddDependencyInjection(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Validator
        services.AddTransient<IValidator<OAuthLoginRequest>, OAuthLoginRequestValidator>();
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
                .AddFluentValidation(options =>
                {
                    // Automatic Validation
                    options.AutomaticValidationEnabled = false;
                    // Automatic registration of validators in assembly
                    options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                });

// Register Dependency Injection Service Extension
builder.Services.AddDependencyInjection();

var app = builder.Build();
```

I registered it in DIServiceExtension and then in Program.cs.

I deliberately post the Login without username and password, but the application did not display any validation message.

This is what I got in Postman:

Response body

```
{
  "response_code": null,
  "response_description": null,
  "data": null,
  "size": 0,
  "access_token": null,
  "refresh_token": null,
  "expires_in": null,
  "token_type": null
}
```

I expected it to display the validation message.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1816#issuecomment-905262805),

```cs
options.AutomaticValidationEnabled = false;
```

is used to disable the automatic validation feature.

---

**Approach 1: Automatic validation**

1. Remove `options.AutomaticValidationEnabled = false;` from registering FluentValidation services.
2. Enable automatic validation with `builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();`.

```cs
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;

builder.Services.AddControllers()
                .AddFluentValidation(options =>
                {
                    // Automatic registration of validators in assembly
                    options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                });

builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
```

Reference: [FluentValidation/FluentValidation.AspNetCore (Automatic Validation section)](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation.AspNetCore#automatic-validation)

---

**Approach 2: Manual validation**

1. In the Controller, get the injected `IValidator<OAuthLoginRequest>` service.
2. In the `Login` action, manually perform validation via `await _validator.ValidateAsync(request);`.
3. If fail validation, add the error(s) from the `ValidationResult` into `ModelState` and return the response with `BadRequest`.

```cs
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    private readonly IValidator<OAuthLoginRequest> _validator;

    public AuthController(IValidator<OAuthLoginRequest> validator)
    {
        _validator = validator;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route(ApiRoutes.Login)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<OAuthLoginResponse>> Login([FromBody] OAuthLoginRequest request)
    {
        ValidationResult validationResult = await _validator.ValidateAsync(request);

        if (!validationResult.IsValid) 
        {
            // Add error into ModelState
            validationResult.AddToModelState(ModelState);

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var result = await _myService.Login(request);
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

```cs
public static class FluentValidationExtensions 
{
    public static void AddToModelState(this ValidationResult result, ModelStateDictionary modelState) 
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors) 
        {
            modelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: [FluentValidation documentation (Manual Validation section)](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#manual-validation)